# Test frequency range of EMC tests

Tags: emc

Very stupid question, but I haven't found a convincing explanation anywhere else:
The test frequency for most EMC tests is from 10s of kilohertz to 100s of megahertz. Testing any lower doesn't makes sense because the energy is too low. But why don't EMC tests cover higher frequencies (gamma-rays, UV radiation)? Is it beacuse the exposure for terrestrial applications to those radiations are lower (in terms of energy, instensity)?

Answer (score 3):

> The test frequency for most EMC tests is from 10s of kilohertz to 100s of megahertz.

US radiated emissions tests go to 40 GHz. European standards go to 6 GHz, IIRC. Who told you they only go to 100's of MHz?

> But why don't EMC tests cover higher frequencies (gamma-rays, UV radiation)? Is it beacuse the exposure for terrestrial applications to those radiations are lower (in terms of energy, instensity)?

Emissions in the optical range (infrared, visible, and UV) are easily blocked by any opaque object. They are unlikely to interfere with other equipment because even a simple plastic enclosure around that equipment will block them. And any equipment that could be sensitive to visible radiation will already have appropriate shielding to be sure it will work when, for example, it's used outside under ordinary sunlight.

Gamma rays are probably not tested simply because it's highly unlikely to produce them with ordinary electronic devices if you aren't deliberately trying to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer